# MySQL modifies the date I insert

Tags: mysql, timezone, mysql-date

```
insert into wp_processed values ('306186837','John Wick','Marketplace','2020-06-19 12:21:10','My Dog T-Shirt','5XL','Green','1','79');
```

And when I select the inserted row it shows that date data is inserted with +3 hours.

```
2020-06-19 15:21:10
```

What am I missing ?

Thanks

Comment: What's you local timezone? What's the timezone on your MySQL server?

Comment: timezone GMT +3, in MySQL it says SYSTEM, I am not sure but seem like it is UTC

Comment: What is the type of the column?

Comment: datetime, mysql seems to change timezone for inserted string automatically to UTC, I am trying to prevent this on insert.

Comment: There you go. The MySQL server is storing your data as GMT/UTC. So you'll need to get it back to your local timezone when you select it. `SELECT CONVERT_TZ(date_col, '+0:00', '+3:00') FROM wp_processed;`

Comment: @Dougie when I save to database, it automaticall adds 3 hours, and your CONVERT_TZ also adds 3 hours. So final result is 6 hours difference. My local time is gmt +3, I can get what I want by changing it to -3 of course. But I want to do it proper way, and by understanding.

Comment: Are you East or West of Greenwich?

Comment: server is in amsterdam, and my location is in istanbul.